# Why gradle is unable to resolve a dependency version even if only 1 dependency version is strict?

Tags: gradle, dependencies, gradle-dependencies

The following gradle dependency constraint:

```
        constraints {

            api("org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:1.0.6") {
                version {
                    strictly ("1.0.6")
                }
            }
        }
```

Is causing the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':parent:mldsl:compileTestFixturesScala'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':parent:mldsl:testFixturesCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:{strictly 1.0.6}.
     Required by:
         project :parent:mldsl
      > Cannot find a version of 'org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12' that satisfies the version constraints:
           Dependency path 'com.tribbloids.spookstuff:mldsl:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.12.16' (compile) --> 'org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:1.0.6'
           Constraint path 'com.tribbloids.spookstuff:mldsl:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'com.tribbloids.spookstuff:mldsl:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT' (apiElements) --> 'org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:{strictly 1.0.6}'
           Dependency path 'com.tribbloids.spookstuff:mldsl:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'org.scalatest:scalatest_2.12:3.2.12' (compile) --> 'org.scalatest:scalatest-core_2.12:3.2.12' (compile) --> 'org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:2.1.0'
           Dependency path 'com.tribbloids.spookstuff:mldsl:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.12:2.4.8' (compile) --> 'org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.12:2.4.8' (compile) --> 'org.json4s:json4s-jackson_2.12:3.5.3' (compile) --> 'org.json4s:json4s-core_2.12:3.5.3' (compile) --> 'org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:1.0.6'

   > Could not resolve org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:1.0.6.
     Required by:
         project :parent:mldsl > org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.12.16
         project :parent:mldsl > org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.12:2.4.8 > org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.12:2.4.8 > org.json4s:json4s-jackson_2.12:3.5.3 > org.json4s:json4s-core_2.12:3.5.3
      > Cannot find a version of 'org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12' that satisfies the version constraints:
           Dependency path 'com.tribbloids.spookstuff:mldsl:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.12.16' (compile) --> 'org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:1.0.6'
           Constraint path 'com.tribbloids.spookstuff:mldsl:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'com.tribbloids.spookstuff:mldsl:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT' (apiElements) --> 'org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:{strictly 1.0.6}'
           Dependency path 'com.tribbloids.spookstuff:mldsl:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'org.scalatest:scalatest_2.12:3.2.12' (compile) --> 'org.scalatest:scalatest-core_2.12:3.2.12' (compile) --> 'org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:2.1.0'
           Dependency path 'com.tribbloids.spookstuff:mldsl:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.12:2.4.8' (compile) --> 'org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.12:2.4.8' (compile) --> 'org.json4s:json4s-jackson_2.12:3.5.3' (compile) --> 'org.json4s:json4s-core_2.12:3.5.3' (compile) --> 'org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:1.0.6'

   > Could not resolve org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:2.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :parent:mldsl > org.scalatest:scalatest_2.12:3.2.12 > org.scalatest:scalatest-core_2.12:3.2.12
      > Cannot find a version of 'org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12' that satisfies the version constraints:
           Dependency path 'com.tribbloids.spookstuff:mldsl:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.12.16' (compile) --> 'org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:1.0.6'
           Constraint path 'com.tribbloids.spookstuff:mldsl:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'com.tribbloids.spookstuff:mldsl:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT' (apiElements) --> 'org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:{strictly 1.0.6}'
           Dependency path 'com.tribbloids.spookstuff:mldsl:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'org.scalatest:scalatest_2.12:3.2.12' (compile) --> 'org.scalatest:scalatest-core_2.12:3.2.12' (compile) --> 'org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:2.1.0'
           Dependency path 'com.tribbloids.spookstuff:mldsl:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.12:2.4.8' (compile) --> 'org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.12:2.4.8' (compile) --> 'org.json4s:json4s-jackson_2.12:3.5.3' (compile) --> 'org.json4s:json4s-core_2.12:3.5.3' (compile) --> 'org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:1.0.6'
```

From the information, it is clearly seen that there is only 1 strict version declaration:

```
:{strictly 1.0.6}
```

This should theoretically supercede all other versions. What may cause the resolution to fail?

Comment: what version of Gradle are you using? what version of Java? This would help efforts to reproduce.

Comment: `scalatest_2.12:3.2.12` seems to want `scala-xml_2.12:2.1.0` but you are forcing to use the `1.0.6` version so this breaks. At least, this is a layman reading of the error. You may want to change your `scalatest` version to something that supports `1.0.6` as `scala-xml` dependency